# Working with two instances of visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug two different issues with the same git branch. I'm doing this to save sometime as one of the issues requires too much processing time after each input. In the interim period I work on the other issue.

To do this I have opened two instances of visual studio 2015 and running two different instances of the application(one for each). Now I get confused to figure out which instance is for which issue.

Is there any way to tag/flag one of the instances for the ease of identification?

I tried by changing the theme but that change in one becomes effective for other instance as well.

Comment: Why not add comment for every instance in your project code with "//"? You could describe the real issue you want to result in this case before you really check in this project. Or type in /// before your method, property, etc. VS will generate the comment blocks automatically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary.

Comment: This is none of those.

Comment: If possible, you could share a screen shot about this issue, how did you really run two instances of the app? Like my previous understanding, if you mean just run the same app with two different folders(also use two VS Editors), maybe you could view the output folder or open the windows explorer for  them to classify it. Like the theme or others, it will be changed for all the instances of the VS, it couldn't resolve your issue. If I misunderstood this issue, please feel free to share it here.